# using jQuery deferred objects to work with a jQuery collection/array serially

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have an array of jQuery objects. I'd like to interact with each item in the array if they are visible. My flow goes something like this:

1. Create an array, whose elements are all jQuery objects.
2. The objects may or may not be visible.
3. Start with the first element in the array.
4. Wait for the item to be visible, time is arbitrary. Say 3 seconds. If becomes visible, go to step 5, else return from 'play' function.  // Updated
5. Click the item.
6. Repeat 4-5 until there are no more items left to be interacted with.

**UPDATE (clarification of use case):**
Essentially what I'm doing is performing a series of serial actions on an array. A-B-C-D, in order. However there may be an issue when A creates B's element and B has already been checked if it was visible. It won't get clicked on.

I've been looking at jQuery's deferred object, but am at a loss on how to implement it. How can this be implemented? Is there an alternative to using a deferred object?

As per @jmort's suggestion I'll attach what I have so far.

```
var play = function() {
    var dfds = []; 
    $(steps).each(function(i, v) {
        dfds[i] = $.Deferred();
    }); 

    $.when.apply(null, dfds).then(function(){
        console.log('all done');
    }); 

};
```

Assume that steps equals the array of jQuery objects.

Comment: Perhaps include a code example of what you've tried so far or at least some of the code you're working with. It gives everyone something to work with when looking at your question.

Comment: @jmort253: Sure. I can do that. Thanks.

Comment: There's no need to use a deferred unless you want to implement some async scenario ("here are the items and here's what to do on them when X happens; I don't have a clue when X might happen or even what X might be").

Comment: @Jon: So would a series of callbacks be better suited for this scenario? Essentially what I'm trying to do is this: execute A-B-C-D. But they have to be in order.

Comment: @kennethkoontz. Is my answer valid for that need? Or do you want to wait for all the `steps` elements to be visible?

Comment: @gdoron: Yes your answer is valid. But the problem that I can see with it is if a previous step creates the next step's dom element to be interacted with. This is my fault though for not explaining it in the question. Updating.

Comment: @gdoron: I updated the flow, to give a better idea on what needs to happen. The waiting aspect is really what needs to happen, this is why I thought it may be better to use a deferred object as you never know when the next element in the steps array is going to be visible.

Comment: @gdoron: Well I don't know if this would work if you waited for each element to be visible, but I suppose n+1 steps would work.

Comment: I meant, when you click `A` what happens? an async operation like `ajax` request? does it invlove callbacks?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11083/discussion-between-kenneth-koontz-and-gdoron)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done easily:

```
var play = function() {
    $(steps).filter(':visible').click();
};
```

**Update:**

```
var play = function() {
    $(steps).each(function() {
        $(this).filter(':visible').click();
    });
};​
```

Comment: Bah, this is a perfect answer for my question. Thanks. However, I forgot to add in the fact that it's possible for a step, when clicked, will create the next steps dom element. In which case, wouldn't this plow right through it? I'll update.

Comment: @kennethkoontz. What do you mean by _" will create the next steps dom element"_

Comment: Ok so the steps array is created, it may or may not include visible elements. Heres a scenario and lets just suppose the steps array includes [A,B,C,D] where A is visible, B is not, C, is, and D is. Also, lets assume that B will become visible when A is clicked. So when the array is processed, It's possible that A will be clicked and the next element will not be clicked (which you want to happen). Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @kennethkoontz. How much time after the click of `A` until `B` becomes Visible?

Comment: Well that's the thing, I suppose a setTimeout would work, but that seems dirty and arbitrary. Don't you think? Ideally you want to go to the next step, immediately when it is available, which may be .1 seconds from now, or 4 seconds from now. However, just to get a prototype working, I may just do it for 2 or 3 seconds.

Comment: @kennethkoontz. The only thing that is important is: whether the click callback of `A` use async operations, like `AJAX`, `setTimeout`, callbacks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11085/discussion-between-gdoron-and-kenneth-koontz)